# Subdomain adding a folder to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect...

http://blog.example.org/folder/name-of-page.html

...to....

http://www.example.org/different-name-of-page.html

For my .htaccess file under blog.example.org I've added...

```
Redirect 301 /folder/name-of-page.html http://www.example.org/different-name-of-page.html
```

However, when I do this it takes me to http://www.example.org/blog/folder/different-name-of-page.html

For some reason it's auto-populating the /blog/folder/ part instead of taking me to the URL I've suggested.

Any idea on a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's interferring with rewrite rules that you have that map subdomains to folders. Use mod_rewrite instead of the `Redirect` directive.

Before any of your other rules, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/name-of-page\.html
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.org/different-name-of-page.html [L,R]
```